# Removing skylight from resin storage shed

Tags: roof, shed

I have a 10 ft. x 8 ft. [Keter Stronghold Resin Storage Shed](https://www.homedepot.com/p/US-Leisure-10-ft-x-8-ft-Keter-Stronghold-Resin-Storage-Shed-157479/100652232?MERCH=REC-_-pipsem-_-NA-_-100652232-_-N)

The roof panel slides off due to several broken tabs on skylight so I have to remove the old skylight by unsnapping the roof panel. 
***How do you unsnap the roof panel from the skylight panel?
I heated the tabs and tried using a screwdriver but have't been able to unsnap these plastic parts from each other. The other option is to break the other skylight tabs holding the roof panels but I dont want to damage the roof panels in the process. [image: interior roof and skylight]

Answer (score 3):

See pages 24 and 33 of the [instruction manual](https://images.homedepot-static.com/catalog/pdfImages/61/61b75264-fed4-4c87-a3fd-850c6b6adf84.pdf). The ridge was installed first, and the roof panels slid in place. You'd need to do the opposite to take them out.

If you struggle to get the tabs released, rotate the panel one direction, release the first clip, rotate a bit more, release the second.... It may help to have an assistant, or you could use wood shims to set all tabs in the released position and just give the whole works a tug.

Answer (score 1):

If the objective is to remove the skylight for disposal and not re-use, consider to use a reciprocating saw or similar keyhole saw to cut away around the tabs. Heating not the tabs but the skylight under the tabs may permit you to distort them sufficiently, but it's also destructive.