# Repairing leaking shed skylight

Tags: roof

Several of the tabs on my sheds "skylight" have broken off and now the roof leaks. What can I use to cover this area and stop the leaking?

Comment: What kind of tabs? Are they really sky lights or are they "skylights"? What is the roof made out of? If you'd [edit] to include some clear, focused pictures of the problem (over view shot and some close up detail shots of the broken parts), someone might be able to help you. Otherwise, it's going to be hard to give you any advice more detailed than "slather roofing tar on it".

Comment: Lacking any pictures [edit] those in - or details, I'll just point you here on the assumption that it's shed with a hunk of clear plastic corrugated roofing inserted. https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/260904/18078 Shinier than just tar so it holds up to sunlight better.

Answer (score 1):

If it's something like this [removing skylight from resin storage shed](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/170417/removing-skylight-from-resin-storage-shed) then I would suggest simply putting on some disposable gloves or using a popsicle stick and smearing a liberal amount of Silicone Caulk (clear or colored) in and around the tabs or their previous areas.

A few coats or applications would be very good for a decade. If there are rather large holes or gaps, then just use duct tape as a backer from the inside to start with. After a day or two you can trim the tape overhang down and smear the backside a few times for a solid patch.